# matlab simulink X-t graph

Tags: matlab, simulink

ı have to made it more clear .. sorry, silly of me :(
ı add a picture for my calculation to the link.

[image]

**t** (in the **X1** calculation) value changes from 0 to **e*tz***. if its valeu reach **etz** it have to start from 0 again and again. This situation have to continue during simulation (we need a Loop!). But you know **t** is simulation time and I cannot force it to be zero so maybe ı need a parallel time to the simulation time but ı dont how to create it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

it seems i didn't understand correctly.

You want B-A for given simulation times. But B is a matrix from 0:2A. Do you have several Bs for each time?

You can do the following:

Compute A. Then diverge the signal A to N diferrent multiplicators. where N is  0:N:2A.

Each of the outputs of the multiplicator is a value of B. Then you substract A to B and there you have, X agains t.

Comment: sorry, ı think ı couldnt explain the problem. the problem is that I couldnt create a loop for every B calculation during simulation. because B have to start from 0 again if it reach 2A but B depends on simulation time as u can see so ı cannot force the simulation time to be zero for the next calculation... thnx for your interest..

Comment: @prot Well if you cant do it in Simulink, export the data to the workspace and run a .m to plot it as you want. You can actually make Simulink to run a .m when it finishes the simulation, so it seems the best option. However check my edit before doing this, I am not sure if a Understand 100% so check.

Comment: @prot Its not working is not enaugh information. Sorry, youll have to be more specific on what you tried if you want help.

Comment: thank you guy for your interest. I couldnt give you enough information for solving the problem. The modulo function worked fine as I wished. The magical code for the loop was **mod(t,e*tz)**. thank you so much for your interest again..